# powershell : a way to get real IOPS generated by script

Tags: powershell, io, performance-testing

I am working on performances issue on scripts that are slow when logging on a remote share.

Is there a command that get a count of real I/O sent to the disk system ?

Lots of scripts exists to mesure the IO performance, but I am unable to find a tool that mesure the I/O generated by a specific script

I would like to have at the end of the execution the number of I/O generated the script XY.

Comment: There's `Measure-Command`, but it's just running time. How are you writing into the log? Open - write 1 line - close - repeat pattern is pretty inefficient even on local disk, never mind network share.

Comment: Of course it is ugly, and it replicate exactly some applications in production.  A shinny piece of software liked by the users is not always efficient ly written, and of course not provided with the source code

Comment: Is it a Windows platform?